prove the speed of a smooth regular curve on a manifold is smooth/continuous
I am reading some chapters from Lee's books on smooth manifolds as well as Riemannian manifolds. However, maybe since I skipped many contents, I find it difficult to prove the following seemingly easy result, which I hope someone can help me with.
Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensioanl Riemannian manifold with or without boundary and $\gamma: [a, b] \to M$ be a smooth regular curve. For any $t_0 \in [a,b]$, following Lee's definition, the velocity of the curve at $t_0$ is the tangent vector
$$\dot{\gamma}(t_0) = d\gamma\vert_{t_0}\left(\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t_0}\right).$$
With a Riemannian metric, the speed is then defined as $|\dot{\gamma}(t)|=\left<\dot{\gamma}(t), \dot{\gamma}(t)\right>^\frac{1}{2}$. I am struggling to prove the speed is a continuous function on $[a,b]$. This will become true if it is smooth, but how to prove it when the Riemannian metric is involved?

I think it should be sufficient to note that the speed is obtained as the composition of smooth functions, i.e., the differential of $\gamma$ and the Riemannian metric.

Thanks for your comment. I have wrote down an answer from its inspiration.

I think I have got an answer which is not 100% satisfactory, it needs us to accept the following result from Lee's books.
Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold with or without boundary, then for any $p \in M$, we can find some open neighborhood $U$ containing $p$ and smooth orthogonal frame $(E_i)$ on $U$ such that $g = g_{ij}\varepsilon^i\varepsilon^j$ on $U$, where $(\varepsilon^i)$ are the dual coframe of $(E_i)$. In particular, $g_{ij}$s are smooth functions on $U$.
Now with this result, let us define $h: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $h(t) = \left|\dot{\gamma}(t)\right|= \left(g_{ii}[\gamma(t)][\dot{\gamma}^i(t)]^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}$, where $(\dot{\gamma}^i(t))$ are coordinates with respect to some smooth local orthogonal frame which I believe should be smooth. Since everything involved in the preceeding expression is smooth, $h$ is smooth hence continuous.

It is not smooth, only continuous (you loose smoothness at points with zero velocity).

My curve is regular so no zero velocity.

Oh, I did not notice this assumption.
